# Object Using name of prototype function name instead of its property

Tags: javascript

I created two function A and B. Made A as prototype of B. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WbZfz/)

```
function A(){

}

function  B(){
    this.name ="Class B";
}

B.prototype = A;
var b = new B();
alert(b.name); // expected Class B got A
```

I know I should have used `B.prototype = new A();`

Is above behavior expected? 
Is it possible to get "Class B" instead of "A" in above scenario?

**Note:** I am using above because A has some property associated with it as `A.text = "Text"` `A.text1 = "Text2"` and I want these property available to B. so `B.prototype == A.prototype.` can not be used.

Comment: `B.prototype = A;` is assigning the function `A` to the prototype of `B`, that's probably _not_ what you want.

Comment: That scenario seems irrelevant since you'd probably never want to do that, but yes, you can get `"Class B"` in implementations that don't support the non-standard `.name` property  on functions.

Comment: ...though it does seem odd that you couldn't assign a property since `this` is the object, not the prototype.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the possible duplicate [What is the reason to use the 'new' keyword at Derived.prototype = new Base](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12592913/1048572) and also at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13418980/1048572) on why there are no "classes" in javascript.

Yes, the behaviour is expected. `B.prototype`, the object from which your `b` instance inherits, is the function object `A`. So, it does inherit its [`name` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name) which is the string `"A"`.

And, this property is immutable (its property descriptor is `{configurable: false, enumerable: false, value: "B", writable: false}`), so when you try to assign a new value to `b.name`, [this will check](http://es5.github.com/#x8.7.2) for [`[[CanPut]]`](http://es5.github.com/#x8.12.4) which returns `false` - and nothing happens. in strict mode, an `Invalid assignment in strict mode` TypeError would be thrown ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WbZfz/2/)).

You only could overwrite it using [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

---

@Edit: I'm not sure why you want those properties inherited by `B`. They are "static attributes" of the `A` constructor function and they should stay there. There is currently no way to let a Function inherit from anything else than `Function.prototype`, so either you go with copying them or your don't use them. Tell us for what you'd need them, and we can find a solution.

Changing the `prototype` property of functions (and objects in general) does not make them happen to inherit from anything else. The `prototype` property of functions points to the object from which newly created (constructed) instances will inherit.

Comment: Ah - and that property is not mutable.  Durr.  I've been scratching my head for a couple of minutes now.

Comment: The point is that the inherited `"name"` property is non-writable, so the attempt to create an own property with that name fails.

Comment: I just wanted to know why  prototype property is given more preference than own property?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas As for I know if you create an object which have same prototype name as its prototype. You can access both property using __proto__ and directly accessing by property name. That means there are tow layer. in above case name "A" is property of prototype. why is it not allowing  instance of B to have its own property.
?

Comment: @Sushil Well, read my comments in the other answers. If the inherited property is non-writable, you cannot shadow it by simple assignment. The "name" property of the `A` function is non-writable, so `this.name = ...` inside `B` fails.

Comment: @Sushil the deal is this: when you mention `name` in an expression, the runtime first has to determine whether `name` is a symbol that's already defined. In this case, it **is** defined, and it's defined as a non-mutable property of the prototype.  Thus, the assignment statement does nothing at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `B` to "inherit" from `A`, write:

```
B.prototype = Object.create( A.prototype );
```

Comment: Do you understand why the code as written behaves the way it does?  I'm confused by it; maybe I'm just tired :-)

Comment: Explain why that's better than `new A`, what the drawbacks are and I'll give you an upvote :-)

Comment: @Pointy It appears that it's not possible to shadow an inherited `"name"` property, if it belongs to a function: http://jsfiddle.net/hG64d/1/ I'm not sure why, I'll have to investigate.

Comment: http://jsperf.com/object-create-vs-constructor-vs-object-literal/7 indicates that using new is faster than object.create

Comment: @SanderRoesink Those options are not the same. The first two create an object which inherits from `Object.prototype`, whereas the last one creates an object which inherits from  `Obj.prototype`, which in turn inherits from `Object.prototype`.